# Spring initialiser dependencies for a REST consumer console application

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I am a Spring Boot newbie. I'd like to initialise a project which consists of:

1. A console application that acts on command line arguments so the JAR files could be later used in scheduled tasks.
2. Consumes a RESTful service
3. Logging

Which package dependencies should I choose in [Spring Initializer](http://start.spring.io/)? Apart from the necessary packages, are there any libraries that are optional but make development easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how you want to consume the restful service, but you may not need any extra starters, the core `spring-boot-starter` that you get when you just hit "Generate Project" and is usually implied with all the common starters like `-web`, `-security`, .. has logging and dependency injection and is all you need to create a jar that can easily be started with `java -jar`

However, it does not come with `RestTemplate` which is a common way to build rest clients in spring. For that you'll need to manually add a dependency on `org.springframework:spring-web` like you can see examples for in https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/

But you can as well use other rest client libraries if you like them better.

There is also Feign that can be used as rest client and it's available from the initializer, examples at https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-feign.html - have not tried it and I'm not sure how much extra cloud dependencies will be added when you add the starter.

I also like having [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) in all projects but that's preference. The obvious sounding choice of [DevTools](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html) doesn't give you much benefit in a console application but is great for live reloading of web servers.

> [...] so the JAR files could be later used in scheduled tasks.

sounds like you're trying to create a library / module of a larger application. You don't need an application that works standalone for that though so maybe https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/ is good to read for you. Difference for libraries is that you don't need the spring boot plugin for maven/gradle which can package a standalone jar, just the dependency management.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your suggestions. I think I'll give **Feign** a chance. This will be a standalone application and not a part of a bigger one. One question: If `spring-boot-starter` already contains the common starters, then why are `Web` and `Security` both available as dependencies?

Comment: @Disasterkid the starter without suffix is not one that contains everything, unlike in other projects. If you want a webserver in your application you need the -web starter and so on. The starter dependencies are meant to give you all the (3rd party) dependencies and spring configuration needed to have for example a -web application. And if you want mongo DB as your DB you add that starter on top.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "the starter without suffix". True I don't need the `Web` dependency because that's for making Web applications. So should I just initialize my project with Security, Feign and the corresponding database libraries e.g. Postgres?

Comment: @Disasterkid security is also mostly for web servers, I don't think you'll need that unless you want some form of authentication in commandline parameters. What I meant is that `spring-boot-starter` is just the core, unlike e.g. `aws-java-sdk` which represents the entire sdk and adding a suffix gives you a subset, e.g. `aws-java-sdk-s3`  is just the "s3" part. I'd pick the minimum to start with, i.e. feign if you want to try that. And if you need access to postgres, add `Jpa` (see https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/) and `PostgreSQL`